# Change Default Program Install Path from SSD to Secondary HDD

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, ssd

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Kingston 120 GB SSD. I plan on installing several programs, including Steam, that will take up quite a bit of space, so I installed, formatted, and partitioned a 1 TB HDD. Is it possible to change the default installation path of programs, or possibly even on a program by program basis? An older similar post suggested mounting an additional harddrive or partion as /usr or as /usr/share, but I am not sure if this is relevant to my issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Ubuntu's programs, but with Steam you can specify another partition. When you go to install a game choose the drop down and choose create a new library on /boot then this will open where you can install to. Goto /media/YOURUSER/Your drive..folder. Then you can create a folder here and install games to it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the programs you install in Ubuntu, with the package manager will go to somewhere under `/usr`. However, other locations will also take up considerable space (`/var/lib`, I'm looking at you!).

Steam, however, is a different beast. Although some of it's libraries are installed under `/usr`, the bulk of it is installed somewhere else: `~/.local`, which is under `/home`.

My suggestion would be to mount your HDD as `/home`.
This would solve your Steam problem and allow you to save lots of data in your home dir.
It's not as fast - admittedly, but how often is disk I/O the bottleneck when accessing the data under your user's home?